# What does loosey-goosey mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/loosey-goosey?q=+loosey-goosey
I wonder if it means **easy**?

It cannot be as loosey-goosey as just wanting to drive loyalty with all consumers. You have to know which consumers you’re targeting and what type of loyalty you’re driving. What is it that you actually want them to do? Do you want them to spend on more profitable products or services? The next thing is to make sure that whatever you’re trying to accomplish with the loyalty program is consistent with your overall company strategy and brand messaging.

Source:https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/marketing-and-sales/our-insights/customer-loyalty-the-new-generation?cid=soc-app

Comment: It's the 2nd definition at your oxford link. Imprecise, inexact, sloppily conceived, ...

Comment: Loosey-goosey is bad.